# Issue with XML comparison using XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

The two xmls I am trying to compare are:

```
<root>
   <a id ="tanvi">test</a>
   <a id ="aj">ram</a>
   <b id = "56">test</b>
   <a id ="kartikey">test2</a>
   <d>
   <c foo = "bar">textchange</c>
   </d>
</root>
```

and

```
<root>
   <a id ="tanvi">test2</a>
   <a id ="aj">ram</a>
   <b id = "56">test</b>
   <d>
   <c foo = "bar">text</c>
   </d>
   <d>
   <c foo = "soo">textchange</c>
   </d>
 </root>
```

I want the application to give me the following differences:

```
<a id ="tanvi">test2</a>    vs <a id ="tanvi">test</a>          text value change
<a id ="kartikey">test2</a> vs null                             not found
<c foo = "bar">text</c>     vs <c foo = "bar">textchange</c>    text value change
<d></d>                                 not found
```

I have tried using `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` as well as the `ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier`. But I am not getting the desired results.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DetailedDiff detailedDiff = null;
        try {
            FileReader base = new FileReader(new File(
                    "C:\\xml\\Test2\\test_Swap.txt"));
            FileReader upgrade = new FileReader(new File(
                    "C:\\xml\\Test1\\test_Swap.txt"));

            XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(Boolean.TRUE);
            XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(Boolean.TRUE);

            try {
                detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(base,
                        upgrade));
                // detailedDiff
                // .overrideElementQualifier(new
                // ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
                detailedDiff
                        .overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());
                detailedDiff
                        .overrideDifferenceListener(new MyDifferenceListener());
            } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Difference> listOfDifferences = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
        for (Difference diff : listOfDifferences) {

            if (diff.getId() == 22) {
                if ((diff.getControlNodeDetail().getValue().equals("null") && diff
                        .getTestNodeDetail().getValue().equals("#text"))
                        || (diff.getTestNodeDetail().getValue().equals("null") && diff
                                .getControlNodeDetail().getValue()
                                .equals("#text"))) {
                    System.out
                            .println("******************VALUE CHANGE*******************************");
                    System.out.print("Base Xpath: "
                            + diff.getControlNodeDetail().getXpathLocation()
                            + "\t");
                    System.out.println("Value: \'"
                            + diff.getControlNodeDetail().getValue() + "\'\t");
                    System.out.print("Test Node Xpath: "
                            + diff.getTestNodeDetail().getXpathLocation()
                            + "\t");
                    System.out.print("Value: "
                            + diff.getTestNodeDetail().getValue() + "\t");

                    System.out.println("Difference ID: " + diff.getId());
                    System.out.println("Difference: " + diff);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + diff.getDescription());
                    continue;
                }

            }

            System.out
                    .println("*************************************************");
            System.out.print("Base Xpath: "
                    + diff.getControlNodeDetail().getXpathLocation() + "\t");
            System.out.println("Value: \'"
                    + diff.getControlNodeDetail().getValue() + "\'\t");
            System.out.print("Test Node Xpath: "
                    + diff.getTestNodeDetail().getXpathLocation() + "\'\t");
            System.out.print("Value: \'" + diff.getTestNodeDetail().getValue()
                    + "\'\t");
            System.out.println("Difference ID: " + diff.getId());
            System.out.println("Difference: " + diff);
            System.out.println("Description: " + diff.getDescription());
        }

    }
}
```

*I am using the `DifferenceListener` to ignore these differences:

```
   public class MyDifferenceListener implements DifferenceListener {
    private static final int[] IGNORE_VALUES = new int[] {
            DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH_ID,
            DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID,
            DifferenceConstants.ATTR_SEQUENCE_ID,
            DifferenceConstants.HAS_CHILD_NODES_ID };

    static {
        Arrays.sort(IGNORE_VALUES);
    }

    private boolean isIgnoredDifference(final Difference difference) {
        int differenceId = difference.getId();
        for (int element : IGNORE_VALUES) {
            if (differenceId == element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int differenceFound(final Difference difference) {
        if (isIgnoredDifference(difference)) {
            return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
        } else {
            return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedComparison(final Node node, final Node node1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The `ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier` is giving me these results:

```
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1] Value: 'test'   
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1]'   Value: 'test2'  Difference ID: 14
Difference: Expected text value 'test' but was 'test2' - comparing <a ...>test</a> at /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1] to <a ...>test2</a> at /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1]
Description: text value
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[3]   Value: 'a'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]' Value: 'd'  Difference ID: 10
Difference: Expected element tag name 'a' but was 'd' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[3] to <d...> at /root[1]/d[1]
Description: element tag name
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[3]   Value: '1'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]' Value: '0'  Difference ID: 11
Difference: Expected number of element attributes '1' but was '0' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[3] to <d...> at /root[1]/d[1]
Description: number of element attributes
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[3]/@id   Value: 'id' 
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]' Value: 'null'   Difference ID: 2
Difference: Expected attribute name 'id' but was 'null' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[3]/@id to <d...> at /root[1]/d[1]
Description: attribute name
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[3]/text()[1] Value: '3'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]'    Value: '1'  Difference ID: 17
Difference: Expected node type '3' but was '1' - comparing <a ...>test2</a> at /root[1]/a[3]/text()[1] to <c...> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]
Description: node type
******************VALUE CHANGE*******************************
Base Xpath: null    Value: 'null'   
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]   Value: #text    Difference ID: 22
Difference: Expected presence of child node 'null' but was '#text' - comparing  at null to <c ...>text</c> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]
Description: presence of child node
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/@foo Value: 'bar'    
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[2]/c[1]/@foo'   Value: 'soo'    Difference ID: 3
Difference: Expected attribute value 'bar' but was 'soo' - comparing <c foo="bar"...> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/@foo to <c foo="soo"...> at /root[1]/d[2]/c[1]/@foo
Description: attribute value
```

The `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` is giving me these results:

```
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]   Value: 'a'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]' Value: 'd'  Difference ID: 10
Difference: Expected element tag name 'a' but was 'd' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[1] to <d...> at /root[1]/d[1]
Description: element tag name
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]   Value: '1'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]' Value: '0'  Difference ID: 11
Difference: Expected number of element attributes '1' but was '0' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[1] to <d...> at /root[1]/d[1]
Description: number of element attributes
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/@id   Value: 'id' 
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]' Value: 'null'   Difference ID: 2
Difference: Expected attribute name 'id' but was 'null' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[1]/@id to <d...> at /root[1]/d[1]
Description: attribute name
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1] Value: '3'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]'    Value: '1'  Difference ID: 17
Difference: Expected node type '3' but was '1' - comparing <a ...>test</a> at /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1] to <c...> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]
Description: node type
******************VALUE CHANGE*******************************
Base Xpath: null    Value: 'null'   
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]   Value: #text    Difference ID: 22
Difference: Expected presence of child node 'null' but was '#text' - comparing  at null to <c ...>text</c> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]
Description: presence of child node
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[3]/@id   Value: 'kartikey'   
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/@id' Value: 'tanvi'  Difference ID: 3
Difference: Expected attribute value 'kartikey' but was 'tanvi' - comparing <a id="kartikey"...> at /root[1]/a[3]/@id to <a id="tanvi"...> at /root[1]/a[1]/@id
Description: attribute value
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/@foo Value: 'bar'    
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[2]/c[1]/@foo'   Value: 'soo'    Difference ID: 3
Difference: Expected attribute value 'bar' but was 'soo' - comparing <c foo="bar"...> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/@foo to <c foo="soo"...> at /root[1]/d[2]/c[1]/@foo
Description: attribute value
```

Which `ElementQualifier` should I use or override any method to get the desired results?

-----------------EDIT 1-----------------------------------------

On using `XMLUnit.setCompareUnmatched(false)` in conjuction with `ElementNameAndTextQualifier`, the differences are identified correctly.

Results using this are:

```
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1] Value: 'test2'  
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1]'   Value: 'test'   Difference ID: 14
Difference: Expected text value 'test2' but was 'test' - comparing <a ...>test2</a> at /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1] to <a ...>test</a> at /root[1]/a[1]/text()[1]
Description: text value
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]    Value: 'text'   
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]'  Value: 'textchange' Difference ID: 14
Difference: Expected text value 'text' but was 'textchange' - comparing <c ...>text</c> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1] to <c ...>textchange</c> at /root[1]/d[1]/c[1]/text()[1]
Description: text value
*************************************************
Base Xpath: /root[1]/d[2]   Value: 'd'  
Test Node Xpath: null'  Value: 'null'   Difference ID: 22
Difference: Expected presence of child node 'd' but was 'null' - comparing <d...> at /root[1]/d[2] to  at null
Description: presence of child node
*************************************************
Base Xpath: null    Value: 'null'   
Test Node Xpath: /root[1]/a[3]' Value: 'a'  Difference ID: 22
Difference: Expected presence of child node 'null' but was 'a' - comparing  at null to <a...> at /root[1]/a[3]
Description: presence of child node
    Description: presence of child node
```

Any other method that I could use or override?

Comment: Please share the code for DifferenceListener  as well.

Comment: I think you are pretty close with ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier and XMLUnit's default of matching unmatched nodes against "some random node" is biting you.  `XMLUnit.setCompareUnmatched(false)` should remove quite a few of your extraneous differences.

Comment: @tanvi isn't the result exactly what you wanted?

Comment: @StefanBodewig If I remove the attributes, the results are as if the comparison is being done sequentially. But I guess that is how the ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier will work. I want the results to be on the basis of text if the attributes do not exist. I am overriding qualifyForComparison() for this.

Comment: @tanvi XMLUnit is recursing into the matched nodes first, so you see the Text node differences before the missing nodes.  If you want to match on nested text if there is no attribute to match then you really have to implement `ElementQualifier` yourself.  You can subclass `ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier` and reuse its `areAttributesComparable` method in order to avoid duplicating too much.